# symfony error message "Binary replacement failed, rename /usr/local/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/__symfony__bak ..."

Tags: symfony

My symfony's version does not want to update, when I do a symfony -v, this message appears:

> "Binary replacement failed, rename /usr/local/bin/symfony
> /usr/local/bin/__symfony__bak: permission denied. Rollback and
> continue".

I manually tried to rename:
`sudo mv /usr/local/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/__symfony__` (two dashes before and after the "symfony") ,
or `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/__symfony`

But it does not work,

what should I actually do? Thanks for your help

Comment: is the directory location correct? I notice a few odd bits: there's a space behind the first "symfony", the user is called "usr", and it looks like "usr/local/bin/symfony" is called twice behind each other, unless that space seperates them.

Comment: Hi, Steven, there is a space behind the first /usr/local/bin/symfony

Comment: I have had that happen to me a few times with symfony ending up under /usr directory somewhere.  Updates will fail without using sudo which in turn is a pain when symfony tries to update itself.  The symfony executable should be under $HOME/.symfony/bin/symfony at which point permissions are not longer an issue.  Consider removing symfony and reinstalling it until it ends up under $HOME.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 4):

What I did was...

Give all permissions to folder:

```
chmod a+rwx /usr/local/bin
```

Then went to the folder and changed the name of the symfony file to "__symfony__bak:" without quotations.

Then wrote a command that triggered the update installation. In my case:

```
symfony server:start
```

This message popped up:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/symfony: No such file or directory

Then changed the name of the file back to "symfony" without quotations.

Then wrote the same command again.

```
symfony server:start
```

In this case the installation was successful and no error message popped up.

And it worked! I hope it works for you as well if you didn't fix it already.

Comment: It worked fine for me, though I had to use `sudo chmod`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**

I had the same issue with

```sh
symfony check:requirements
```

Simple use `sudo`-command and problem was solved

```sh
sudo symfony check:requirements
```